# Second Window Positioning WPF

Tags: wpf, window, size, width

I have MainWindow which has a button that allows it to open another WPF Window. I want this window to open always on the right hand side of the MainWindow practically right next to it.

How can I do this? This needs to work even if the width of the MainWindow changes as I have various buttons on the MainWindow that can change the size of the MainWindow depending on what panel is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate where you want the new window if you have a reference to the other window.

Get the other windows position by accessing the Left and Top properties and its width by accessing the ActualWidth or the Width property.

Now you can calculate the new windows position by adding Left + Width + Some spacing.

Check out the documentation for the Left property here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.left.aspx

The others behave similarily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set manual startup location for second window in properties or in code:

```
WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
```

On events Loaded, SizeChanged, LocationChanged of first window, you should adjust position of second window like this:

```
    public void AdjustPosition()
    {
        window2.Left = Application.Current.MainWindow.Left + Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth;
        window2.Top = Application.Current.MainWindow.Top;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            AdjustPosition();
    }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
           AdjustPosition();
    }

    void MainWindow_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           AdjustPosition();
    }
```